# Apple will approve paypal integration on token purchase or not?

Tags: paypal, in-app-purchase

I want to purchase some token from my server , for this i am implementing **paypal sdk**.
But i want to know that apple will allow this **paypal integration** for token purchase or they will force me to use **inAppPurchase**?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's guidelines are quite clear on that. It depends on what you are selling. There are even things for which they don't want you to use In-App Purchase. IAP is strictly for content, service or funktionality of your app or consumed within your app.

IAP ist not designed for anything else.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: can you please answer of my question?

Comment: Have a closer look. My answer says "it depends on what you are selling". Which is some sort of reply-qutesion as "What do you intend to sell?" Once you told us what you plan to use paypal for then you may have a chance of getting a "no" or "yes" answer. Maybe.